# Instantiating a Class of Library Objects?

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

I have a question regarding C++ classes and instantiation.  The output for the code below is as follows:

Poco library for quick ref : http://pocoproject.org/docs/

this is a test
EXITING

I want the output to be:

this is a test
username
EXITING

Basically, why isn't the myCreds printing out?
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPBasicCredentials.h>

using namespace std;

class myTest{
public:
    string test;
    Poco::Net::HTTPBasicCredentials myCreds;
    myTest();
};  

myTest::myTest(){
    test = "this is a test";
    Poco::Net::HTTPBasicCredentials myCreds("username", "password");
}

int main(){
    myTest thisTest;
    cout << thisTest.test << "\n";
    cout << thisTest.myCreds.getUsername() << "\n";
    cout << "EXITING" << "\n";
}
```

Thanks for the help.
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two instances of `myCreds`: one that belongs to `thisTest`, and one that is created and destroyed in the body of the constructor of `myTest`.

You should write the constructor for myCreds as folows (to innitialize the member `myCreds` correctly):

```
myTest::myTest()
    : test("this is a test")
    , myCreds("username", "password")
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring myCreds as a local variable in your class constructor, overriding the public variable in your class. The local variable disappears when your constructor returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is creating its own `myCreds` rather than initializing the member variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are re-creating a local instance of `HTTPBasicCredentials` as opposed of initializing your public member here:

```
myTest::myTest(){
    test = "this is a test";
    Poco::Net::HTTPBasicCredentials myCreds("username", "password");
}
```

The myCreds instance inside that constructor will be created and thrown away when the construction finish.

Initialize your public member instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it all makes sense now